# If I'm going to Italy via Germany, what country should my Schengen Visa be for?

Tags: schengen-visas

Taking Lufthansa from NYC to Munich and then, on the same day, carrying forward to Italy. To which consulate should I apply for my Schengen Visa?

Comment: How long will you stay in Italy and what country is the most important part of your visit. (If you have an important meeting in Germany and just one or two nights in Italy it will be a different answer from when you do not have anything important in Germany and more nights in Italy.)

Comment: If you're a US passport holder and are just traveling for a reasonably short period of time (a few weeks or less), especially for pleasure, you won't need a visa.

Comment: There is not enough information in this question to give a definite answer.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on what you plan to do (the main purpose of your visit) as *Willeke* mentioned. Say if you have a business visa and have a meeting, then you would apply to the consulate where you have the meeting.

Whereas, if you have a tourist visa and your main tourism will occur in Italy you will apply at the Italy consulate.

Answer (score -4):

The Visa should be in your case from Italy , since you are transitting from Munich.

If however you intend to break your journey even for a night in Munich , you should go for Germany.

Schengen Visa Rules for first port of entry

It is the country that is your first destination in the region. More often than not, you will have to apply to the country which is your port of entry. As per the Schengen visa rules first port of entry is usually the country that issues your visa.

Check with the airlines where the immigration is going to happen , most likely it will be Italy.

Comment: Substantiate your claim please. AFAIK, this advice is wrong.

Comment: @AnishSheela you are correct.  The advice is wrong.  The threshold for having to apply in Germany rather than Italy is rather higher than spending even one night in Germany.

Comment: Not wrong answer , if you read the question , it says Lufthansa , and Munich is one of hub where the connection needs to be taken for concourse...No offence though

Comment: the answer is wrong, UNLESS the traveler never passes through customs in Munich in which case (s)he will not have entered Germany at all.

Comment: This answer ignores the 'most important part of your stay' rule as well as ignores we do not know enough about OP themselves.

Comment: Good that moderator closed the question... :-)

Comment: @jwenting how does a traveler arriving in Munich from the United States get to a flight bound for Italy without passing through Schengen passport control?

Comment: Regarding the edited answer, this material is incorrect: "More often than not, you will have to apply to the country which is your port of entry. As per the Schengen visa rules first port of entry is usually the country that issues your visa."  The Schengen visa code specifies that the *main destination* country is the competent authority to consider a visa application and issue a visa.  The country of first entry is only competent if it is not possible to identify a main destination.

Comment: @phoog not sure, never been in that situation. I've however been on board planes that merely made a fuel stop and let some people on and off, the through-passengers remaining on board. This wasn't a Schengen area thing though so might be different.

Comment: This answer contains 5 paragraphs, of which each single one is wrong. Why is it still there?

Comment: @KristvanBesien Because sadly answrs can't be removed on the basis of them being disastrously wrong